# Prove the following statements using the indicated method (by contradiction)

Tags: solution-verification

I have a problem here hope you will help me.

**Let a be an integer. If $a^2-3$ is odd then $3a+2$ is even.**

I am asked to prove this by contradiction.

**Example:**
*Proposition*
For all integers $n$, if $n3 + 5$ is odd then n is even.

*Proof.*

Let $n$ be any integer and suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $n 3 + 5$ and $n$ are both odd. In this case integers $j$ and $k$ exist such that $n 3 + 5 = 2k + 1$ and $n = 2j + 1$.
Substituting for $n$ we have $$2k + 1 = n 3 + 5 2k + 1 = (2j + 1)3 + 5 2k + 1 = 8j 3 + 3(2j) 2 (1) + 3(2j)(1)2 + 13 + 5 2k = 8j 3 + 12j 2 + 6j + 5$$
We found $2k = 8j 3 + 12j 2 + 6j + 5$. Dividing by $2$ and rearranging we have $k − 4j 3 − 6j 2 − 3j = 5 2$ . This, however, is impossible: $5/2$ is a non-integer rational number, while $k − 4j 3 − 6j 2 − 3j$ is an integer by the closure properties for integers. Therefore, it must be the case that our assumption that when $n 3 + 5$ is odd then $n$ is odd is false, so $n$ must be even.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a proof by contradiction. $a^2 - 3$ is odd $\implies a^2$ is even $\implies a$ is even $\implies 3a + 2$ is even. $\blacksquare$

*Edit:* A proof by contradiction. If possible, suppose $3a + 2$ is odd. As $2$ is even, $3a$ must be odd. So, $a$ must be odd. This implies that $a^2$ is odd, and so $a^2 - 3$ is even (difference of two odd numbers is even). This contradicts our hypothesis that $a^2 - 3$ is odd. So, $3a + 2$ must be even. $\blacksquare$

Comment: that is why i ask bro, how?

Comment: See my edit @Namdosan